# Is there a way to select the CSSi ID of a container which is generated by JS fecthing data from an API

Tags: javascript

I'm building a page that shows some products and the data is coming from an API. 
The page is built with JS/es6 and Bootstrap4. 
What I did until now was to fetch the data and with a forEach to generates the product cards dynamically with the API data.

Example:

```
listOfProducts.forEach(product => {
    // We create a template a blueprint for our cards and passing with literal template
    // Dynamically as foreach will loop and for every product in the array will print the card
    // using ${product.title} we pass the title of the product from JSON OBJ of our products
    // fetched from API
    out += `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 py-2">`;
    out += `    <div id="${product.asin}" class="card h-100 d-flex flex-column">`;
    // To img we give src of the img from JSON OBJ and ALT the ASIN
    out += `        <img src="${product.img}" class="card-img-top" alt="${product.asin}">`;
    out += `        <div class="card-body">`;
    // We pass product title & price from JSON OBJ
    out += `            <h5 class="card-title">${product.title}</h5>`;
    out += `            <p class="card-text">${product.price}$</p>`;
    // Button add to cart & skip
    out += `            <button class="btn add-to-cart"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></button>`;
    out += `            <button class="btn skip"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>`;
    out += `        </div>`;
    out += `    </div>`;
    out += `</div>`;

  });
```

My problem is when I started to work on the add to cart button inside the example above. What I would like to achieve now is that when I click the button the card should get the class selected which changes the border to be green but I'm unable to get the selected CSS id and append or attach thee selected class to it.

I tried as follow:

```
let test = row.querySelector('.add-to-cart').addEventListener('click', product => {
    const productId = document.querySelector(`#${product.asin}`);
    productId.class.add('selected');
 });
```

But the console is giving me an error as my product is not defined or if I put the same inside the forEach my product id is null.

I'm trying to find out the best solution for it as what I would like is to be clear as follow:

- click button add-to-cart
- the clicked product gets selected class and board change color to green

My full script is here:
[mainjs](https://pastebin.com/TxqbyqD7)

Comment: Well the first question you have to ask is what the resultant ID attributes are in your output HTML. Are they what you're expecting?

Comment: So I'm passing the asin of this API https://api.myjson.com/bins/18fh4d into 
`<div id="${product.asin}" class="card h-100 d-flex flex-column">`
and on the page I see this: `<div id="B00KQG4806"></div>` which is the id I'm passing from API to identify the single product via CSS selector. It is was I'm expecting to see inside the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening becasue your event callback is evaluated only when the event fires - by which time, `product.asin` relates to the last item of the iteration only, since iteration has finished. In fact, if you're binding the event outside the `forEach`, you'll be getting an error, since `product` is defined only locally in the `forEach` scope, not outside it. That would be throwing an error in your console. Always check the error console.

Another problem is that you're assuming that the first argument passed to the event callback is the triggering element; it's not, it's an event object. And so you need its `.target` property:

In any case, you don't need to concern yourself with IDs to do what you're trying to do. You can just find the container element relative to the clicked add-to-card button.

Note also that `class.add` should be `classList.add`; that too will have been causing an error in your console.

Finally, bear in mind that it makes little sense to assign the return value of an event listener (which is `undefined`) to a variable (`test`, in your case.).

And so:

```
row.querySelector('.add-to-cart').addEventListener('click', evt => {
    evt.target.closest('.card').classList.add('selected');
 });
```

Comment: Your solution is giving me the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: btn.closest is not a function

Comment: Edited. I inherited your error of assuming the first element passed to the event callback was the triggering element.